# How to style only this element if condition is true or false?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write jQuery that will loop over every div with the class name `.content_txt` and check its height is over 60px. If true, then set that element to `height:auto`; if false then set this element height to `60px`.

The problem is that there are more divs with that class on page. How do I style only the specific div based on the condition?

Is it possible to add a rule to this element attribute style with jQuery without rewriting existing rules? For example, in my HTML document there is this structure of this element:

```
<div class='content_txt' style="background-color:f00;">..content</div>
```

keep background-color and add `height` with parameter.

My jQuery:

```
$('.content_txt').each(function(){
     if($(this).height > 60){
       $(this).css('height','auto');
     }else{
       $(this).css('height','60px');        
     }
});
```

Comment: height is not a property in jquery, it is a function, so use height(); in ur code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

height of jquery is function and not property. so use `.height()`:

```
 if($(this).height() > 60){
    //rest code
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.content_txt').each(function(){
     if($(this).height() > 60){
       $(this).css('height','auto');
     }else{
       $(this).css('height','60px');        
     }
});
```

[height()](https://api.jquery.com/height/)

Comment: So my code is fine ? I mean it style only this div and not others ?

Comment: @user3342042, height is not a property in jquery

Answer (score 0):

`height` is a function and not a property.

So, you have to do `if($(this).height() > 60){}`