# CSS: How to fix unnecessary gaps

Tags: html, css

Here is my problem(open in new tab to see it more clear)[image]

You can see the result and my code in this page. The problem is that there is an unnecessary gap between a and c,d. How fill this gap?

https://jsfiddle.net/vqonmqk5/2/ (make sure you make the result field as big as the above one)

```
Thanks in advance!
```

EDIT: I don't want to use fixed or absolute positions to fix this

This is what I want to achieve:
[image: What I want to achieve]

IMPORTANT!: The divs are created by php(in my web page) with data from a SQL database, so I don't want to use things like absolute positioning. And I also don't want to use external libraries.

Comment: please post the fiddle showing the problem.

Comment: The link is already in my question: https://jsfiddle.net/vqonmqk5/1/

Comment: But that does not show what you did in the picture...

Comment: The link shows a different result.

Comment: @blobliebla No, we won't, it's different CSS.

Comment: I checked it and you were right, sorry. New link is: https://jsfiddle.net/vqonmqk5/2/

Comment: @blobliebla Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: @Blubberguy22 done! Sorry for my mistake :/

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/vqonmqk5/8/
It's not that pretty but it does what you want. Works with a wrapper around the 4 items and some `floats`

Comment: No, I don't mean that. See my question for the thing I want to achieve

Comment: Updated the answer. It's like you wanted.

Comment: Its just partly what I want. I am going to create this divs from php code with data from a SQL-database. Then your solution is not going to work :/ But thanks for trying it.

Comment: Why wouldn't that work? As long as you pass along those ID's it should be the same.

Comment: The number of divs is variable and the size too, so I don't know if the float of the div has to be left or right.

Comment: Well, unless you write a script where it gets a float left or right based on the width on the div it's not possible with just html/css. You will have to write a function for that. Like this for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864664/how-to-style-only-this-element-if-condition-is-true-or-false

Answer (score 0):

There is not one solution to your problem. You could position your div's absolute or rebuild your construction.

What is the purpose of your code? Is it for a responsive buildup?

Comment: The divs will be generated with php. It loads data from a database and put it in a div. So I don't want to use absolute positioning

Comment: I should go for the solution @Stefan Neuenschwander gave you

Comment: No that is not what I want to achieve. See my question for what I want to achieve(the last picture)

Answer (score 0):

Thats how floats work. Because the div `b` has a taller height, `c` and `d` have to clear that height then slide left. Because `a` is shorter there is a gap. It's working as expected.

You may want to look into a library like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). It looks like it might achieve what you are after.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't want to use any external libraries. And I know the way floats works, but can you maybe give me some alternatives?